How to deserialize a complex nested object from JSON using jsons
I'm trying to deserialize a complex nested object from JSON using the jsons library.
The returned object from jsons.loads has the correct type but the nested objects are all of type 'dict'
Is there a way to deserialize into the full nested object where the nested objects have the correct type?
Here's a basic example:
import jsons

class Inner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = False
        self.name = "Inner"
    
class Middle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Middle"
        self.inners = []
        for x in range(4): self.inners.append(Inner())      

class Outer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Outer"
        self.middles = []
        for x in range(3): self.middles.append(Middle())
            
myOuter = Outer()
print (type(myOuter))             # --> <class '__main__.Outer'>
print (myOuter.middles[1].name)   # --> Middle

myJson = jsons.dumps(myOuter)
reloaded = jsons.loads(myJson, cls=Outer)
print (type(reloaded))             # -->  <class '__main__.Outer'>
print (reloaded.name)              # -->  Outer
print (type(reloaded.middles[1]))  # -->  <class 'dict'>
print (reloaded.middles[1].name)   # -->  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'



(I'm guessing you use jsons)
You must tell jsons what is the type of sub dicts.
You can do that by defining class attributes and their types.
Here is a short example with Outer class:
class Outer:
    middles: list[Middle]

Doing so, here is the result of your two last lines:
print(type(reloaded.middles[1]))  # <class '__main__.Middle'>
print(reloaded.middles[1].name)  # Middle


Here is the complete changes you need to do in your code:
class Inner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = False
        self.name = "Inner"


class Middle:
    inners: list[Inner]

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Middle"
        self.inners = []
        for x in range(4): self.inners.append(Inner())


class Outer:
    middles: list[Middle]

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Outer"
        self.middles = []
        for x in range(3): self.middles.append(Middle())

